# How to set CharacterEncoding using H2 database?

Tags: jdbc, h2

when using mysql, we set jdbcurl like this `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&password=&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=gbk&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false`

`characterEncoding=gbk` implies we use gbk encoding for Chineses,

now I am using H2 in my project, but cannot find how to set encoding for h2?
anyone can help?

`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS` show me `property.file.encoding:utf-8`, but I cannot find how to change this config.

Comment: Just store the data as a String (VARCHAR or CLOB data type).

Comment: @Abi sorry, I still cannot get the point, I wish to store the content as GBK encoding, and avoid encoding&decoding when handling the data.

Answer (score 0):

In Java-initiated H2 environment the H2 database is using whatever encoding is passed inside your JVM arguments (if none is passed, then it will use the environment default). In Spring Boot environment you can use following inside your POM to change the encoding to UTF-8:

```
<properties>
    <spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</spring-boot.run.jvmArguments>
</properties>
```

Note that this only works in your local environment when running the application with command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

If you need to change file encoding for server environments, then you should use environment variables or pass the parameter directly with JVM arguments within the java command that you use like so (tested on Windows PowerShell):

```
java "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" -jar filename.jar
```

In other environments it might be that you need to leave out the hyphens (not tested):

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar filename.jar
```

Still, in other than local environment best would be setting it up as an environment variable.